# Magnetic hysteresis energy loss derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

we have that the magnetic energy stored in a field is :
$$W_m = \frac{1}{2}\int_v B.H dv$$

From here im unsure how to get to the expression that the power dissapated in a hysteretic cycle is given by :
$$W_{cycle} = \int H.dB$$

Which is commonly quoted as the energy dissipated i.e. the loop area. As far as I see it we start and finish with the same magnetic energy stored in out field and so I'm unsure how to derive this second formula.

Comment: Your second equation is more fundamental then your first and it is the first that should be derived from the second rather then the other way round.

Comment: Ahh okay. Could you perhaps point me to where to find a derivation of it?